# Python Geolocator Geocode location in None but still works + random string is added (weirdest error I ever saw)

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, geopy

I have at the moment to figure out where "favicon.ico" comes from. It is really super weird.

I use geopy to geocode a location into latitude and longitude, then I use these values to create markers on a google map (Flask GoogleMaps).

That is the piece of code:

```
try:
    print findroomcity
    location = geolocator.geocode(findroomcity)
    print location, location.latitude, location.longitude

    if location:
        mymap = Map(
        identifier="view-side",
        lat=location.latitude,
        lng=location.longitude,
        markers=[(location.latitude, location.longitude)],
        zoom = 12
        )
    else:
        print "location is none"
```

In this case `findroomcity` is "dortmund". It is actually grabbed from a form.

If I submit the form the map is actually created, so it does not use the `else block` But it tells me that location in NoneType and has no attribute latitude. It seems that **it calls the try block three times and the first time `findroomcity` is "favicon.ico", also the last time**

Check the outputs of the prints:
[image]

I dont even used "favicon.ico" in my whole project, I know it must be somewhere but I checked every .py file and also searched for every `print`. I am really super confused, I keep searching, but maybe someone has encountered something similar.

Here is the whole method which creates the map:

```
# Die Filter Funktion mit Google Maps
@app.route('/<findroomcity>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def find_room(findroomcity):
    form = FilterZimmerForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        query = Zimmer.query
        filter_list = ["haustiere_erlaubt","bettwaesche_wird_gestellt","grill_vorhanden","safe_vorhanden","kuehlschrank_vorhanden","rauchen_erlaubt","parkplatz_vorhanden",
                "kochmoeglichkeit_vorhanden","restaurant_im_haus_vorhanden","handtuecher_werden_gestellt","tv_vorhanden","waschmoeglichkeit_vorhanden","wlan_vorhanden"]

        for filter_name in filter_list:
            if getattr(form, filter_name).data:
                query = query.filter(getattr(Zimmer, filter_name).is_(True))

        all_rooms_in_city = query.all()

        else:
            all_rooms_in_city = Zimmer.query.order_by(desc("stadt")).all()  


        try:
            print findroomcity
            location = geolocator.geocode(findroomcity)
            print location, location.latitude, location.longitude

            if location:
                mymap = Map(
                identifier="view-side",
                lat=location.latitude,
                lng=location.longitude,
                markers=[(location.latitude, location.longitude)],
                zoom = 12
                )
           else:
               print "location is none"



        except AttributeError as e:
            flash("Ort nicht gefunden")
            print e
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        except GeocoderTimedOut as e:
            print e

    sleep(1)
    return render_template('zimmer_gefunden.html', mymap=mymap, all_rooms_in_city=all_rooms_in_city, findroomcity=findroomcity, form=form)
```

**EDIT**

I have really no idea where it comes from, I use now:

```
if location.latitude is not None:
```

Comment: I have not used Flask but googling "flask favicon.ico 404" gives you the documentation to specifically address this error http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/favicon/

Comment: What does this have to do with my question? I know how to add a favicon in flask...

Comment: But why it prints it there and why geolocator tries to create a latidute from the the "favicon.ico" string? If I add the favicon the error disappears of course.

Comment: Can u post your template code?

Comment: The Issue is solved, the template is really huge and SO code block does not format it right so I would need 20 min to intend everything, I still dont know why geopy printed favcion, but including favicon solved the issue, btw @roganjosh if you answer it, I`ll accept